# merge two sub arrays in php with backslash

Tags: php, arrays, merge

i have an array like this:

```
array(2) {
   [0]=>
   array{
      [name] => "Category"
   }
   [1]=>
   array{
      [name] =>"Sub-category"
   }
```

}
I want array like this

```
array {
    [name] => "Category / Sub-category"
}
```

thanks.
I tried to use array_merge and implode functions, but can't figure out proper way

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by combining [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'Hello'],
    ['name' => 'World'],
];

$new = [
    'name' => implode(' / ', array_column($array, 'name')),
];
```

`$new` now contains:

```
array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(13) "Hello / World"
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/Z6RMK)

Comment: @Abay - Feel free to accept the answer so others know it's been resolved.